# Flex: Varying tick heights on HSlider?

Tags: actionscript, flex3, slider

I've placed an HSlider in my Flex application with values 0-10.  I would like the tick marks at 0,5, and 10 to be longer than the rest so that they give the user some visual reference to where they are in addition to the labels and datatip.  Any idea how to do this? Ideally you could supply an array to the tickHeight parameter, but unfortunately it only allows a single number.  Here's my slider:

```
<mx:HSlider id="mySlider"
value="5"
styleName="label2"
tickOffset="7" 
tickLength="5"
labelOffset="30"
labels="['LO','HI']"
tickInterval="1"
change="broadcastChange(event)"
liveDragging="false"
minimum="0" maximum="10"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way is to code a custom track skin class (not really hard)
Take a look here for some pointers: http://forums.adobe.com/message/2486681#2486681#2486681